# how to append to body httprequest c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest

I have a request coming from a client. I want to append the data in the body from the client and then send another request with the appended body to another api call. I don't want to remove or override the original data that was passed in the req

Is this possible to do?

Comment: In that case you may be looking at a data storage such a dictionary or database. If it is kept in memory apply the singleton pattern and prevent any race condition. Then what you will have to do is fetch the previous relevant requests associated with a specific client and forward them to a different server.

Comment: You can REST call other service(s) you like while processing the current request. I don't understand your point?

Comment: _"I want to append the data in the body from the client"_ - **what does the request body look like?** - if it's something like a JSON body then you _cannot_ simply append more JSON to it because then it wouldn't be a valid JSON document anymore (as a JSON document must have a single root object/value/array).